# HTML from input element (search box) can't be selected with the mouse

Tags: html, css

At [this site](https://staging.whitewreath.org.au/), the search box at top right does not function.

I tried adding a z-index to the parent element:

```
.col-right-one-thirds {
    max-width: 22.38033333em;
    padding:  1em;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    float: right;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

but that does not resolve the issue.

The search box is a Wordpress search widget.

How can I resolve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div `.col-full` is overlayed atop the header because of the floated divs `.col-right-one-thirds` and `.col-left-two-thirds`

Add `clear: both` to `.woocommerce-active .site-header .col-full`

```
.woocommerce-active .site-header .col-full {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does the position need to be relative?

Comment: no problem. the selector for .woocommerce-active .site-header .col-full already had the position property set to relative, I only added clear: both